# Unable to run an XMLQuery on a XML statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I have a problem with XML queries in SQL Server. I usually run a query on a `@XML` variable to fetch data like this but in a certain statement it does not work.

This code works correctly

```
Declare @XML as XML = 
'
<ResponseData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Remain>12345654321.1234</Remain>
  <ErrorMsg />
</ResponseData>';
;

Select 
    F.value('Remain[1]','decimal(18,4)') as A,
    F.value('ErrorMsg[1]','varchar(100)') as B
FROM  @XML.nodes('ResponseData')Tbl(F);
```

but if I add a new row in the first of `@XML` it can0t parse and return following error

> XML parsing: line 2, character 6, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input

```
Declare @XML as XML = 
'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ResponseData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Remain>12345654321.1234</Remain>
  <ErrorMsg />
</ResponseData>';
;

Select 
    F.value('Remain[1]','decimal(18,4)') as A,
    F.value('ErrorMsg[1]','varchar(100)') as B
FROM  @XML.nodes('ResponseData')Tbl(F);
```

The  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` added to the `@XML` variable.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be any characters between the start of the string and the  `<?xml`

Just remove the line break.

If you want to use utf-16, you'll need to prefix the string with an `N`

```
Declare @XML as XML = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>....
```

Comment: I created an SSIS package that fetch data from a web service task. It fills data into a text file in my disk so I can't modify the statement. Is there another solution?